# How to hide and show a menu in BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, dynamic, menu, bottomnavigationview

I have created an activity with BottomNavigationView and it is working fine.

But I am unable to hide a menu item.

I have tried this code.

bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.tab_email).setVisible(false);

I even tried to call bottomNavigationView.invalidate();

All inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    bottomNavigation.getMenu().removeItem(R.id.nav_user_download);
```

**removeItem(int menu_item_id)**,call this method.

i have try hide/show method @Sachin Rao, but it work not very well. so i finally found this way, it's work well for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me :

```
/**
 * Hides specified item in BottomNavigation View
 *
 * @param id   - id of the menu item - example R.id.profile
 * @param view - instance of BottomNavigationView
 */
public void hideBottomNavigationItem(int id, BottomNavigationView view) {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
        if (itemView.getId() == id) {
            itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly if you set `itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` instead of `itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in above above code that particular menu will be visible

**Update:** easily hide/show menu item in  BottomNavigationMenu

```
public void hideBottomNavigationItem(int id, BottomNavigationView view) {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    menuView.findViewById(id).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public void showBottomNavigationItem(int id, BottomNavigationView view) {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    menuView.findViewById(id).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can using following example:

```
BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_bottom_nav_menu);
menuView.findViewById(R.id.action_menu_need_to_hide).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```